# YouTube: play YouTube video just when click button

Tags: javascript, php, video, iframe, youtube

I have page contain YouTube embed in Iframe and i made it unclickable ,i want to play the video just when I click on play button ,I searched here and on the network and tested them but they don't work :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class='py-3' ><?php echo $course_name?></div>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 px-6 py-6" style='pointer-events: none'>
            <iframe  id='video'
                src="<?php echo $course_video?>">  <!--the Youtube livk is come  from server as : https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxxx -->
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class='row w-100 justify-content-center mt-3'><button  class='btn bg-primary' id='play_video'><i class=" fa fa-play"></i></button></div>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#play_video').on('click', function(ev) {
            $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
            ev.preventDefault();
        })

})
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add semicolons to your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {
    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();
 
  });
});
```

Also you forgot to add the link to your HTML file which is needed for clicking (`<a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />`) and remove `style='pointer-events: none'` from your code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class='py-3' ><?php echo $course_name?></div>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 px-6 py-6">
            <a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />
            <iframe  id='video' src="<?php echo $course_video?>">
            </iframe>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ,but i have the button to be clicked : <button  class='btn bg-primary' id='play_video'>

Comment: Yes, it's not only the button. Look at the rest. For example, you have to remove `style='pointer-events: none'`

Comment: it solved just by removing button tag and set the click function to icon ,and still work by don't remove pointer-events ... Thanks